# Set globa Variables From JSON Variables

Tags: javascript, json

So I have an update function in javascript that get's json variables from a file. I'm using the variables in other functions, and I'm having to call the same file for that function. I'm wanting to set those variables to be global so I won't have to call the file in the other function, Here's the update function:

```
    function XML() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xmlconnect.php",
        dataType: "json",   
        success: function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            var data = data[i]; 
            var level = data[4];
            var cash = data[6];
            var income = data[7];
            var upkeep = data[42];
            var total_income = income - upkeep;
            var eincome = data[46];
            var health = data[10];
            var max_health = data[11];
            var energy = data[12];
            var max_energy = data[13];
            var stamina = data[14];
            var max_stamina = data[15]; 
            var Exp = data[8];
            var max_exp = data[9];
            var attack = data[16];
            var defense = data[17];
            var skill_points = data[24];
            var health_width = health / max_health * 100;
            var energy_width = energy / max_energy * 100;
            var stamina_width = stamina / max_stamina * 100;
            var exp_width = Exp / max_exp * 100;    
            var sess_id = data['sess']; 
            if(cash < 1000) {
            var user_cash = number_format(cash);
            }
            else {
            var user_cash = format(cash);
            }
    $('#Cash').html('$'+format(user_cash));     
    $('#Income').html('$'+number_format(total_income));
    $('#EIncome').html(number_format(eincome));
    $('#LevelText').html(level);
    $('#HealthText').html(format(health)+'/'+format(max_health));   
    $('#EnergyText').html(format(energy)+'/'+format(max_energy));   
    $('#StaminaText').html(format(stamina)+'/'+format(max_stamina));
    $('#ExpText').html(number_format(exp_width)+'%');       
    $('#HealthWidth').css('width',''+health_width+'%'); 
    $('#EnergyWidth').css('width',''+energy_width+'%'); 
    $('#StaminaWidth').css('width',''+stamina_width+'%');
    $('#ExpWidth').css('width',''+exp_width+'%');   
    $('#Update').load('activity.php');
    }
   }
});
}
```

And for instance I need to use a few of those variables in another function called "Increase" And I have it setup like this:

```
    function Increase(Att) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xmlconnect.php",
        dataType: "json",   
        success: function(data) {
        for (var i in data) {
            var data = data[i]; 
            var max_health = data[11];
            var max_energy = data[13];
            var max_stamina = data[15]; 
            var attack = data[16];
            var defense = data[17];
            var skill_points = data[24];    
    $('#AttResults').load('increase.php?att='+Att);     
    $('#Skills').html(number_format(skill_points));
    $('#Att_attack').html(number_format(attack));
    $('#Att_defense').html(number_format(defense));
    $('#Att_max_health').html(number_format(max_health));
    $('#Att_max_energy').html(number_format(max_energy));
    $('#Att_max_stamina').html(number_format(max_stamina)); 
    XML();
    }
   }
});     
}
```

But I want to make the first XML Function to be global Variables.

Comment: No, you don't want them to be global variables. Use a config object and pass that around.

Comment: Add the variables to the `window` object, as thats where other global variable are stored (aka `window["attack"] = data[16]`) - not recommended though. it might be better to use a global variable to store variables _in_ and them request them from that object (aka `var settings = {}` globally, `settings[attack] = data[16]` to se it and `settings.attack` to retrieve.).

Comment: @somethinghere Alright, I'll add that and see how it works out, Sorry for the late reply was busy cleaning around the house a bit.

Comment: @somethinghere Also, would the `var setting = {}` Be outside of the XML Function?

Comment: It would be, you can set a `var` anywhere in your code as long as its not inside another block it'll be global.

Comment: Alright so this is what it showned up After clicking Increase on attack :: [link](http://prntscr.com/6d21g0) It didn't show any of the variables. And I changed all of the Increase Function to something like this `$('#Skills').html(number_format(settings.skill_points));`

Comment: @somethinghere This is how it's setup on the XML Global [Global Var Setup](http://prntscr.com/6d24xb) And here's the Increase function [Setup](http://prntscr.com/6d262o)

Comment: Try to use console.log to debug this as I cannot really help a lot more here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

As per [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) you can simply do:

```
variable = value;
```

(yes, without 'var') and it will make it a global variable unless that same name is used in another scope.

Comment: When you say 'MDN', did you mean 'W3Schools' ? :D But yeah, this is a very correct answer. Its not good practise (how do you know what gets defined where? It muddles things), but thats not the point.

Comment: Yeah I understand that you can put a variable anywhere in javascript, But Considering the data I need for the global variables are inside of a function is confusing me.

Comment: @user3059258 nothing confusing. You can declare the global variable from inside the function. As it's been repeatedly said: not a good practice, but if you want you can do it. Follow the link provided for an example.